# How to insert view bag list of data to local storage?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

as i have multiple checkboxes going to viewbag and getting list of stringfrom selected check boxes.
but how can i store them to localstorage? for using to make my filters checked again after submit

was trying some way but couldn't achieve any help here..?

```
var cc = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Courses));
       console.log("cc",cc)
localStorage.setItem("cc",cc.checked);
checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("#cc"));
   document.getElementById("#cc").checked = checked;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can? But hope this might help you.

```
var cc = '@ViewBag.Courses';
localStorage.setItem("cc",cc);
checked = localStorage.getItem("cc");
document.getElementById("#cc").checked = checked;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).